# os.path.isfile raises FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, exception, os.path

Im just trying to do a little python script for moving a few files to a destination given in a .xlsx file.
For that Im also using the os.path.isfile method.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from os.path import basename, dirname, exists, isfile
from os import rename



wb = load_workbook(filename = 'list.xlsx')
tbl1 = wb['Tabelle1']
i = 2
entry = tbl1['B{}'.format(i)].value
while not entry == None:
    entry = tbl1['B{}'.format(i)].value
    if isfile(basename(entry) + ' (2)'):
        print("Datei doppelt vorhanden")
        i += 1
        continue
    if isfile(basename(entry)):
        print("Verschiebe {}".format(basename(entry)))
        rename(basename(entry),'U:\\' + dirname(entry)[33:] + '/http_download/' + basename(entry))
        i += 1
```

When I run the script it does not print anything I I have to stop it using Ctrl + C. IDLE then shows me that isFile raises a FileNotFoundError which seems kinda weird.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
    st = os.stat(path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden: 'interview_jahn.flv'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\censored\FLV-MP4-Codierung\neucodier_script.py", line 17, in <module>
    if isfile(basename(entry)):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
    st = os.stat(path)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: 'isfile' checks wether a directory entry is a regular file (or another directory). But the entry has to exist. If it doesn't, an exception is raised.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge no, it prints `False` when doesn't exist.

Comment: so is there a method that returns False if it doesnt exist?
edit: @Jean ah yes thats what I thought, too.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You're right!

Comment: Well usually it returns false:
>>> isfile('abc.jpg')
False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an infinite loop, and `entry` is never `None`

```
while not entry == None:
    entry = tbl1['B{}'.format(i)].value
    if isfile(basename(entry) + ' (2)'):
    ...
```

When breaking, you get a `KeyboardInterrupt` which interrupts a (catched) exception handling embedded in `isfile()` (which uses `os.stat` internally, and catches the exception, which is normal when the file doesn't exist).

The error message "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred" doesn't say otherwise. Primary problem here is the infinite loop by your end.